# Captcha JavaScript, should work but

Tags: javascript, captcha

It just wont generate random numbers and input them in span id "broj1" and "broj2". This should work and i cant find any obvious error cause im still new to this. Thanks for help in advance :)

```
        function potvrda(){

        var odgovor = document.getElementById("odgovor").value;
        var broj1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("broj1").innerHTML);
        var broj2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("broj2").innerHTML);
        var zbroj = broj1 + broj2;
        if (odgovor == null || odgovor ==""){
            alert("Molimo unesite zbroj");
            return false;
        }
        else if(odgovor != zbroj){
            alert("Molimo unesite ispravan Broj");
        }

        else{
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing";
            docuemnt.getElemtntById("odgovor").innerHTML = "";
                    }}

        function randomNums(){
            var ran_num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) +1 ;
            var ran_num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) +1 ;
            document.getElementById("broj1").innerHTML = rand_num1;
            document.getElementById("broj2").innerHTML = rand_num2;
        }

    </script>
```

```
        <form method="post" onsubmit="return potvrda();">
        Zbrojite:
        <span id="broj1"></span> + <span id="broj2"></span>=</br>
        <input type="text" id="odgovor" size="50" /> </br>
```

Comment: Please use sane variable / function names in your code.

Comment: If this is the whole code, then you have a syntax error: `SyntaxError: missing } after function body`. Also you don't seem to call `randomNums` anywhere. Learn how to use your browser's developer tools to debug JavaScript!

Comment: `var broj1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("broj1").innerHTML);
        var broj2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("broj2").innerHTML);
        var zbroj = digit1 + digit2;` digit1 and digit2 are undefined. You're setting the fields to broj and broj vars instead of digit1 and 2

Comment: Captcha and JavaScript are two words that should not be in the same phrase. If you expect your captcha to be secure, don't use JavaScript because bots can read the captcha from the code...

Comment: Firstly, check the closing brackets on your functions. Then you also need to call randomNums somewhere or as an anonymous function. Also, ran_num1 and ran_num2 are assigned to broj1 and broj2 as rand_num1 and rand_num2.

Comment: It didnt display body onload="randomNums();"
Aaaand i copied wrong code where i replaced digit1 for broj 1 alredy sorry still not working

Comment: I edited code the way it is now and still not working, i jsut want to load 2 random numbers  in 2 spans... dont understand where syntaxError is i closed brackets and stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining `var ran_num1` and `var ran_num2`, but then you are trying to set the innerHTML of the elements to `rand_num1` and `rand_num2`. You're missing a "d". This fiddle is  working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/68NKQ/

Comment: Yes it actualy generated code on click. thanks i havent noticed extra d letter but still wont work on original file though :/
works on fiddle.

Comment: Tried a little more, you are missing a closing bracket as Sagar Patil mentioned before. I added that bracket and corrected the names of the vars as I mentioned, and now it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/BwL4n/

Comment: I closed baackets on wrong place. YOu helped with indepths explanation. Thanks a lot siboo =)